# Styled Components in React, finding the corresponding component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Pretty new to [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/) and I am liking it. However when building a React app I get ofcourse a lot of elements in the DOM. Sometimes I see a style that needs to be changed. But because the tag is something like:

```
<div class="kOs1nAz">content</div>
```

I have a hard time finding to which component this tag belongs to.

What is the best way to debug/find these styles inside your components? Maybe is there a way to prefix the classname with the component name or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your webpack config - babel plugin you have to set `displayName` to `true`:

```
['babel-plugin-styled-components', { displayName: true }]
```

The class names won't be shortened then.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that using this [`babel-plugin`](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components)

Basically it adds the name of the styled component to the list of classnames.

Hope this helps you.

Here are the [`docs`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling) if you need more information about this.

Comment: please `quote the most relevant part of an important link` - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks. 'Kind user' added the relevant code so I accepted that one. But you were right too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to webpack config, add following plugin, as suggested by [Better debugging](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging):

```
{plugins: [['babel-plugin-styled-components', { displayName: true }]]}
```

If you use create-react-app, you might need [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to modify webpack config.

---

If neither is a good option for you, you can switch from the browser inspector tool to React Dev Tools for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/).

There, look up the tree until you see the name of your component (not styled-component, just the parent component that you export from your file) - that will help you identify which file to look in. Then, use the picker tool to select the relevant styled component inside (e.g. `styled.button`) and look at the structure of elements to help you locate it inside that file.

If you need to debug in a Production build, make sure to use `displayName`:

```
 const MyComponent = ...
 MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent'
 export default MyComponent
```

That will avoid minified names like `t`. If you have to debug before having a chance to add readable displayNames, then you will have to rely on DOM elements `class` attribute for elements where you added a className manually, or check names of props inside React Dev Tools to identify the elements...